# Find any rows contain non numeric in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

How to find any non-numeric value in pandas series?

For example :

```
series = 1,4,5,6,6,-.5,a
```

output =

```
-
a
```

Comment: I think you would want to use pandas [`isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) method
```
series.str.isnumeric()
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the function to_numeric()

Try:

```
output = series.loc[pd.to_numeric(series).isna()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `to_numeric`:

```
series.loc[pd.to_numeric(series, errors='coerce').isna()]
```